# Google Maps refresh polylines

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to refresh google maps without refreshing the page.

I will change `var listPos` to import from an api and I need to refresh the map but, just the polylines not the page, I will add a modal in page for adding new coordinates.

I'm using   `setTimeout(function() {bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);}, 5000);` but it doesn't work. I think it needs to refresh the import from api too, but I don't know how to do it.

My code is:

```js
        var stepDisplay

        function initMap() {
            const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: {
          lat: -23.6085666,
          lng: -46.6663397
                },
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: map
            });

            stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(evt) {
                stepDisplay.setContent(evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
                stepDisplay.setPosition(evt.latLng);
                stepDisplay.open(map);
            });

            var listPos = [{"maps_latA":"-23.577084","maps_lonA":"-46.629042","maps_latB":"-23.611103","maps_lonB":"-46.655907"},
      {"maps_latA":"-23.6039706","maps_lonA":"-46.6637391","maps_latB":"-23.606099","maps_lonB":"-46.668277"}];

            for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
                polylines[i].setMap(null);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < listPos.length; i++) {

                var startPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(listPos[i]['maps_latA'], listPos[i]['maps_lonA']);
                var endPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(listPos[i]['maps_latB'], listPos[i]['maps_lonB']);

                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: map,
                    preserveViewport: false
                });

                calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService, stepDisplay, startPoint, endPoint);

            }
        }

        function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService,
            stepDisplay, startPoint, endPoint) {
            directionsService.route({
                origin: startPoint,
                destination: endPoint,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            }, function(response, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    renderPolylines(response);
                } else {
                    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
        var polylines = [];

        function renderPolylines(response) {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                var steps = legs[i].steps;
                for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                    var stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        strokeColor: 'green',
                        strokeOpacity: 1,
                        strokeWeight: 4
                    });
                    for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                        stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                    google.maps.event.addListener(stepPolyline, 'mouseover', function(evt) {
                        this.setOptions({
                            strokeWeight: 8
                        })
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(stepPolyline, 'mouseout', function(evt) {
                        this.setOptions({
                            strokeWeight: 4
                        });
                        stepDisplay.close(map);
                    });

                    polylines.push(stepPolyline);
                    stepPolyline.setMap(map);
                }
            }
        }
```

```css
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
  <link href="http://code.google.com//apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=pt&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: One way would be to do your "import from API" inside the processing you are currently doing inside the setTimeout callback, then only update the map if the response has changed.

Comment: i create this function `  function getCoords() {
    var listPos;
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1/api/maps.api.php';
    fetch(url)
     .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
     })
     .then((data) => {
      listPos = data;
     })
   }
` but don't work, i'm not so good with javascript

Comment: What does "don't work" mean?  Do you get errors?  You probably need to call the code to process `listPos` inside the callback.  If you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue with sample data, it would be easier to help.

Comment: i don't know how to pull the function inside the callback to use in maps, i tried getCoords(); inside initMap(), but it didn't work, the var listPos is empty

Comment: perhaps this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rz58gw3m/2/) might help.

Comment: I solved it like this. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Doebber/cvhda25m/) In fiddle it doesn't work because there is no valid api link

Comment: That was why my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rz58gw3m/2/) toggled between two sets of sample data